# Mongodb c# driver FindAll with setFields and AsQueryable

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Using MongoDB C# driver, seems that I'm unable to get the data by AsQueryable with setFields and Where condition only by mongo query. I fetched documents by this code

```
var query = _collection.FindAll().SetFields(fields.MongoFieldsBuilder).AsQueryable();
var query1 = query.Where(d=>d.Name="Ken").ToList();
var query2 = query.Where(d=>d.Age>=2).ToList();
```

So, when query1 or query2 executed, c# driver fetches all documents from mongo and then filters it in memory. But I expected that Where condition will be converted to mongo query with fields.
Can anyone please explain how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 5):

You using  `.AsQueryable()` from `System.Linq`, because of this it filter everything on a client side. 
But you need to use `.AsQueryable()` from `MongoCollection` to filter data in a database. This extension method creates `MongoQueryable<T>`.

I believe that following should work:

```
//or you could use your projection class instead of BsonDocument
var query = Items.AsQueryable<BsonDocument>()   
                 .Select(x=> new {id = x["_id"].AsObjectId, Name=x["Name"].AsString});
var query1 = query.Where(d=>d.Name == "Ken").ToList();
```

---

**Update:**

If you want use `SetFields` you have to use old query syntax:

```
_col.Find(Query<UserDocument>.EQ(x=> x.Name, "Ken")).SetFields(..).
```

Also you could use SetFields without magic strings as follow:

```
cursor.SetFields(Fields<UserDocument>.Include(x=> x.Name, x=> x.Age))
```

With linq SetFields is done via `Select`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, but it will be better if I can create query without magic strings or select with magic string, because I want to use mongocsharpdriver Fields builder with SetFields.

Comment: If you want use `SetFields` you have to use old query syntax: `_col.Find(Query<UserDocument>.EQ(x=> x.Name, "Ken")).SetFields(..)`. With linq SetFields is done via `Select`. It seems what you want. No magic strings :)

Comment: Andrew, as I wrote I want to use Linq conditions with setFields. I think is it is possible to add to mongocsharpdriver LinqExtenstion AsQueryable method with parameter IFields and it will more flexible solution.

Comment: No, there is nothing you can currently do.  Andrew's answer above can use linq for the query (Query<UserDocument>.Where(x => x.Name == "Ken").  You can then use the fields builder to set the fields.  However, you are likely using SetFields to only pull back a subset of the data.  This is currently not possible with the linq provider.  There is a ticket open for this: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-456

Comment: What is the type of Items in your example ? I get MongoCursor, how to transform it in IQueryable ?